# How to convert multiple functions to create a generic function

Tags: java, generics

is there a way to convert both methods below to one generic method, i am not being able to pass paramter to generic function initialization

```
public List<Obj1> csvObjConverter(Reader reader) {
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.beginParsing(reader);
    String[] row;
    ArrayList<Obj1> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
        Obj1 obj = new Obj1(row).preprocess();
        objects.add(obj);
    }
    parser.stopParsing();
    return objects;
}

public List<Obj2> csvObjConverter(Reader reader) {
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.beginParsing(reader);
    String[] row;
    ArrayList<Obj2> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
        Obj2 obj = new Obj2(row).preprocess();
        objects.add(obj);
    }
    parser.stopParsing();
    return objects;
}
```

I want to do something like the code below but it is not working:

```
public <T extends AbstractObj> List<T> csvObjConverter(Reader r, Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException {
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.detectFormatAutomatically();
    parserSettings.setMaxCharsPerColumn(90000);
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.beginParsing(r);
    String[] row;
    ArrayList<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
        T obj = clazz.newInstance();    
 // i need something like -> T obj = clazz.newInstance(row);
        objects.add(obj);
    }
    parser.stopParsing();
    return objects;
}
```

---

Comment: *"But it's not working"*.. What exactly is not working? Is the code not compiling? Throwing an exception at runtime? Is your computer catching fire? Please explain the error/exception..

Comment: i am not being able to write a generic function that can combine both those function and what i wrote was not correct code, and that why it is not working

Comment: Are you using Univocity Parsers?

Comment: yes, i am using univocity

Comment: Any reason why you are not using Univocity's `BeanListProcessor`? It directly returns `List`s.

Comment: @manish to be honest i wanted to use that, but i think csv parsing is a simple operation and BeanListProcessor is an overhead  and if in future i want to remove univocity and move to an implementation without univocity, there will be alot of code change (i wanted to do csv parsing without including univocity but the csv doc that i am trying to parse is not clean contain multiple quotes, comma etc that why i used univocity), i want to maintain a code which i can migrate to native operation or any other library easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to invoke a non-parameterless constructor, so `clazz.newInstance()` won't work.

Try:

```
public <T extends AbstractObj> List<T> csvObjConverter(Reader r, Class<T> clazz) throws IllegalAccessException, InstantiationException, InvocationTargetException, NoSuchMethodException {
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    parserSettings.setHeaderExtractionEnabled(true);
    parserSettings.detectFormatAutomatically();
    parserSettings.setMaxCharsPerColumn(90000);
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.beginParsing(r);
    String[] row;
    ArrayList<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    Constructor<T> cons = clazz.getConstructor (String[].class);
    while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
        T obj = cons.newInstance((Object) row);    
        objects.add(obj);
    }
    parser.stopParsing();
    return objects;
}
```

Comment: It worked but i had to make a minor change like this (T obj = cons.newInstance((Object) row);),

Comment: without the above change the program was throwing `java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = 'wrong number of arguments'`,but worked after casting input with Object whereas my constructor parameter is a string[]

Comment: @Shah92 Interesting. I guess that happened due to `newInstance` taking a vararg argument, so the String array passed to it might be interpreted as multiple String arguments.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this solution?

```
public <T> List<T> csvObjConverter(Reader reader, T object) {
    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();
    parserSettings.getFormat().setLineSeparator("\n");
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.beginParsing(reader);
    String[] row;
    ArrayList<T> objects = new ArrayList<>();
    while ((row = parser.parseNext()) != null) {
      T obj = new T(row).preprocess();
      objects.add(obj);
    }
    parser.stopParsing();
    return objects;
  }
```

Whenever you are calling this function, you need to pass the type of object which you are expecting in return.